# How to use pooling on rows, i.e: from (512, 20, 32) to (512, 10, 32)?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, spatial-pooling

I have data with the shape: (512, 20, 32)
and I want to use `AvgPool` and get the shape of: (512, 10, 32).

I have tried with no success:

```
pool = nn.AvgPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
data = torch.rand(512, 20, 32)
out  = pool(data)
print(out.shape)
```

output:

```
torch.size([512, 20, 16])
```

How can I run pool on the horizontal data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pytorch, the dimensions of tensors are `batch`-`channel`-`length`. The pooling layer operates on the `length` dimension (the last one).

There are two workarounds I can think of:

#### 1. Permuting the dimensions

You can change the order of dimension prior to pooling, using [`transpose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.transpose.html):

```py
pool = nn.AvgPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
data = torch.rand(512, 20, 32)
data_permuted = data.transpose(1, 2)
out_permuted  = pool(data_permuted)
out = out_permuted.transpose(1, 2) 

print(out.shape)
```

Output:

> ```
> torch.Size([512, 10, 32])
> ```

#### 2. Adding a singleton channel dimension and using 2D pooling

Adding an additional "empty" channel dimension will turn your 3D input tensor into a 4D one, allowing `nn.AvgPool2d` to operate on the `height` dimension. This adding and removing of singleton dimensions can be done using [`unsqueeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html) and [`squeeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.squeeze.html):

```py
pool = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 1), stride=(2, 1))  # pool only along height dimension
data = torch.rand(512, 20, 32)
out = pool(data.unsqueeze(dim=1)).squeeze(dim=1)

print(out.shape)
```

Output:

> ```
> torch.Size([512, 10, 32])
> ```

---

I believe the second option is more intuitive and might be more efficient than the first one.